# How to use a module inside a folder directly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

Directory Structure:

```
| Packages
    | noobpy
        | __init__.py
        | linalg.py
    | main.py
```

linalg.py:

```
def inv():
    print("inv called")
```

main.py :

```
import noobpy as np
np.linalg.inv()
```

why is np.linalg.inv() not working when the code:

```
from noobpy import linalg
linalg.inv()
```

is working

Comment: You need to add `from . import linalg` to your `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `import`, it expects a package or module, whereas the keyword `from` expects a module, subpackage, class or a function. One simple way to fix is to add `__init__.py` file in your directory noobpy and inside `__init__.py` you should add `import noobpy.linalg`

Once you are done with this you can use

```
import noobpy as np
np.linalg.inv()
```

in your main file.

Note that `__init__.py` makes a directory package and acts like a constructor and does the prerequisites that are defined in this constructor for import to work.